# How do you pronounce $\check{n}$?

Tags: notation, pronunciation

I did search the internet but could not find a source mentioning the pronunciation of the mathematical symbol $\mathbf{\check{}}$ as in $\check{n}$. How do you pronounce it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My professors always pronounced the diacritic "czech", as in "n czech". However, the official name for that symbol is apparently the "caron" or "háček" (hachek), so you could say "n caron" or "n háček".

Comment: I wouldn't spell the English pronunciation "czech", but indeed, [the wikipedia page for caron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caron) mentions "It is also used to decorate symbols in mathematics, where it is often pronounced /ˈtʃɛk/ ("check")."